# Render image is blank

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm new to blender. his is my firs render here and my render image is coming out blank. I followed a tutorial on how o set up a scene to render and when nothing was showing up, I read this blender forum to find an answer, but everything seems in place: light, camera is pointing right at he object, clipping is okay.

I don't know what he problem is, all object are render enabled.

Comment: With the currently provided informations we can only guess. Perhaps you could add a screenshot of your scene.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the object isn't disabled in renders, the camera icon next to the eye icon has to be white for the model to appear in the render,

here is a photo:

[image: camera icon]

edit: I made the mistake of not reading your question all the way through, my apologies, but I will keep this up in case anyone has this problem.

P.S: Have you seen if there are any modifiers on the object(like build)?